# Is there a way to increase the weekly caps?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft, there is a weekly cap for all points you can earn (justice, valor, honor and conquest points).
Is there a way to increase the cap for any of the points? 
If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is different for the different points:

- There are no weekly caps for Honor and Justice points.
- No, there is no way to increase the 1000 Valor points per week cap.
- The Conquest point cap is depended on your Arena / Rated Battleground rating. Further it rises automatically over the course of a PVP / Arena season and is the sum of your unused weekly caps over the season (if you have not earned any Conquest points yet, you should have a cap of around 25.000 by now).

Comment: oh, I think I misunderstood something, but there is a general cap for justice/honor points, which is not based on a certain time, is there a way to increase the cap for honor and justice points?

Comment: No, just spend them then you are near the cap.